# SharePoint Publishing Site - how do I implement reader and search engine friendly URLs?

Tags: sharepoint, friendly-url, seo

I have developed a publishing portal in MOSS 2007 environment. I have some pages whose urls look difficult for end users to read, and are also causing search engines to not index my pages properly.

I went through some articles for implementing the 'friendly url' in SharePoint. I stumbled upon some external tools like 'tinyurl.com', but I don't want to use third party tools for accomplishing this.

I downloaded the 'URL Rewrite' extension for IIS from Microsoft as suggested by many. I tried setting it up, giving it the internal URL name and friendly URL name while creating a rule. The request is made to the friendly URL instead of the internal URL. I don't know where am going wrong.

Should I keep trying to make things work with this extension, or is there another feasible approach I can try?

Comment: Are you certain you have the rules configured properly? This page seems to have a good guideline for this type of work: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: @above thank you very much....i went through the article....am obtaining the '404 not found'......i opened the web.config of my web application and i could find the 'rewrite' tag which contains the rule specified by me....but still the url is not getting rewritten